# Rails and Javascript minifier and aggregator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am starting a new rails project and is there any rails plug in I can use that will minify my  javascript and combine it into 1 file?

I would imagine there might be a rake task for this.

What would be used for this in rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several actually:

- [AssetPackager](http://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager)
- [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/)
- [BundleFu](http://code.google.com/p/bundle-fu/)

I've only used asset packager, and its been nothing but a joy.

Also worth reading:
http://github.com/blog/551-optimizing-asset-bundling-and-serving-with-rails

Comment: Jammit is a really nice all-in-one solution. If you want more flexibility, the GitHub strategy is an excellent starting point.

Comment: I've only used asset_packager as well, but it did everything so well that I didn't find a reason to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Rails has built in javascript file merging.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag

```
javascript_include_tag :all, :cache => true
```

I then use nginx's built in gziping to compress the file size, since it does a pretty good job. There are numerous plugins to do it also:

http://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager/
http://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-yui-compressor/

Answer (score 0):

You might also want want to checkout [Juicer](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/juicer_a_css_and_javascript_packaging_tool). It primarily combines files, but it can work with YUI Compressor and JSLint if you don't mind Java in your toolkit/dependency chain. It's also not specific to Rails, so you could "standardize" on it for all your projects--if you find you like it.

Just an idea.